# C - Changing Characters With Pointers

Tags: c

I am trying to make a game and I am currently making rebindable controls.

These are the variables, with assigned pointers

```
//Controls
char MoveLeft = 'a';
char MoveRight = 'd';
char MoveUp = 'w';
char MoveDown = 's';
char BackButton = 't';
char ConfirmButton = 'y';
char ShowStats = 'u';
char ShowInventory = 'i';
char ShowLegend = 'o';
char ShowControls = 'p';

//Pointers
char *MoveLeftP = &MoveLeft;
char *MoveRightP = &MoveRight;
char *MoveUpP = &MoveUp;
char *MoveDownP = &MoveDown;
char *BackButtonP = &BackButton;
char *ConfirmButtonP = &ConfirmButton;
char *ShowStatsP = &ShowStats;
char *ShowInventoryP = &ShowInventory;
char *ShowLegendP = &ShowLegend;
char *ShowControlsP = &ShowControls;
```

This is my control methods menu function

```
void ControlsMenu(char *MoveLeft, char *MoveRight, char *MoveUp, char *MoveDown, char *BackButton, char *ConfirmButton, char *ShowStats, char *ShowInventory, char *ShowLegend, char *ShowControls) {
//Input
char Input = '0';

//Menu Variables
char ControlNames[] = {MoveLeft,MoveRight,MoveUp,MoveDown,BackButton,ConfirmButton,ShowStats,ShowInventory,ShowLegend,ShowControls};
char *MainMenuNames[] = { "- Move Left", "- Move Right","- Move Up","- Move Down","- Back","- Confirm","- Show Stats","- Show Inventory","- Show Legend"," - Show Controls"};
int MenuChosen = 0;
int *MenuPointer = 0;
MenuPointer = &MenuChosen;
int MinArray = 0;
int MaxArray = 8;
int *ControlPointer = 0;

//Main Loop
do {
    //Loop
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%c", ToUpper(ControlNames[i]));
        ShowMenu(MainMenuNames, i, MenuChosen);
    }

    Input = getch();

    ControlMenu(Input, MenuChosen, MenuPointer, MinArray, MaxArray);

    if ((Input == ConfirmButton || Input == ToUpper(ConfirmButton))) {
        system("cls");
        printf("Chaning key binding for %s\n", MainMenuNames[MenuChosen]);
        printf("Old Binding: %c\n", ToUpper(ControlNames[MenuChosen]));
        printf("Press the key you want to bind");
        printf("%d", MenuChosen);
        Input = getch();
        ControlNames[MenuChosen] = Input;
        //Commit Controls

        switch (MenuChosen) {
        case 0: 
            MoveLeft = Input;
            break;
        case 1: 
            MoveRight = Input;
            break;
        case 2: 
            MoveUp = Input;
            break;
        case 3: 
            MoveDown = Input;
            break;
        case 4: 
            BackButton = Input;
            break;
        case 5: 
            ConfirmButton = Input;
            break;
        case 6: 
            ShowStats = Input;
            break;
        case 7: 
            ShowInventory = Input;
            break;
        case 8: 
            ShowLegend = Input;
            break;
        case 9: 
            ShowControls = Input;
            break;
        }


    }
} while (1);
}
```

And this is how it is called

```
    ControlsMenu(*MoveLeftP,*MoveRightP,*MoveUpP,*MoveDownP,*BackButtonP,*ConfirmButtonP,*ShowStatsP,*ShowInventoryP,*ShowLegendP,*ShowControlsP);
```

Now here is the issue, for some odd reason, the text of the character does change but the actual binding stays the same. The only binding that I can successfully change is the ConfirmButton binding, no matter what I change it to, it works, but anything else like MoveUp or MoveDown doesn't change the actual binding, but only the text shown.

Comment: I suspect your issue may be related to this line: `if ((Input == ConfirmButton || Input == ToUpper(ConfirmButton)))`

Comment: That's what I am thinking actually, remember that, the issue isn't that the confirm button isn't working, it is that ONLY the confirm button is properly changing the binding, whilst the others stay the same

Comment: There issue with only `ConfirmButton` working is almost certainly in `ControlMenu`, but since it's not shown it's not possible to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going on with `ConfirmButton`, but I see an issue with the stuff in your switch statement. Looking at `MoveLeft = Input;` as an example.
`MoveLeft` is a `char*` in your function (i.e. a memory address), but `Input` is a `char` (i.e. an ASCII value). To assign `Input` to the memory pointed to by `MoveLeft`, you need to do `*MoveLeft = Input`. Your compiler should have given you a warning about incompatible assignment there. And similarly for the rest.

By the way, the convention for C variable names is to use lower-case with underscores, or some people do camel-cased with first letter lower. And it's confusing to give all the function params the same names as some global variables.

Comment: I see, and can I change anything with the parameters as well?

Comment: The parameters should work, only the naming isn't ideal.

Comment: More importantly, are you set up with a compiler or IDE that shows you the warnings? Otherwise, these bugs are easy to miss.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio, i'm not sure if its the best to use for this case

Comment: Hmm when I change it to the way you told me to, it gives me a write access violation for each of the cases

Comment: I've never used it, but I'd expect it to be ok.

Comment: The code you've pasted indicates that those variables are pointers, but the behavior you described suggests they're `char`s. There must be a discrepancy somewhere when you made the code example. I'd suggest making your function arguments different from the global variable names for now just to avoid any confusion then go from there. Your `char ControlNames[]` declaration also should be a warning or error.

Comment: Ok I took your advice,
Changed the cases to: *MoveLeftPoint = Input;
Changed the Method Parameters To: void ControlsMenu(char *MoveLeftPoint, char *MoveRightPoint, char *MoveUpPoint, char *MoveDownPoint, char *BackButtonPoint, char *ConfirmButtonPoint, char *ShowStatsPoint, char *ShowInventoryPoint, char *ShowLegendPoint, char *ShowControlsPoint) {

Changed the calling to: ControlsMenu(MoveLeftP, MoveRightP, MoveUpP, MoveDownP, BackButtonP, ConfirmButtonP, ShowStatsP, ShowInventoryP, ShowLegendP, ShowControlsP);

Comment: It ALMOST works perfectly, but it is now showing the wrong characters in the display

Comment: Your functions with 10s 9f arguments are ridiculous.  Create the data structure as pass the  pointer to it